# Are constructions like "That's me out, then" primarily British rather than American?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

Prompted by comments to [this question on English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/) (about *"That's you done"*), I've been searching Google Books for similar constructions of the general form *that's [pro]noun adjective* (for this context, I classify past-tense verb forms such as *done, fucked, finished* as adjectives).

What I seem to be finding is that using *"That's"* in this way (not referencing anything in particular, just "whatever came before/caused the current situation") is a relatively recent phenomenon.

I'm also getting the impression it's more common in BrE than Ame. So by implication, if the boss says to his secretary...

> "Just get those letters off in the post, and that's you done for the day."

...I should assume the boss is probably British, rather than American.

---

Would my assumption be right? Can anyone shed more light on the usage? Is it the same as...

> "Here's me doing all the work while you just sit around waiting to be fed."
>    *(said by, for example, hard-pressed mother to idle teenage offspring)*

Comment: Some people in Australia say 'that's you done' or 'me done' etc. But I don't hear it that often either.

Comment: That doesn't sound very familiar to my AmE ears, but saying, for example, "That's me" while pointing to my beer among a table full of drinks is quite normal.

Comment: Agreed that if this is an Americanism, it's one I've never heard. In your last example, I feel like the hard-pressed American mother would more likely say, "Here I am, doing all the hard work..."

Comment: This kind of construction is commonly heard in Britain, and especially Scotland, where something like "that's me done" is even shortened to just "that's me", e.g. "Right, that's me, I'm off!"

Comment: @tylerharms: I know lyrics don't necessarily have to "mean" much, or follow standard grammar, but I'm tempted to wonder what American ears make of REM's [That's me in the corner \ That's me in the spotlight](http://www.lyrics007.com/R.E.M.%20Lyrics/Losing%20My%20Religion%20Lyrics.html), or Paul Simon's [That's me](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/That's-Me-lyrics-Paul-Simon/C1A69762E93E432A4825716A001035F1). Obviously the singer isn't actually *pointing* to himself in either case, so what exactly does ***that*** reference?

Comment: The answer is british and ameican because at the time of Charles Dickens this phrase was being coined in his head for a future novel that he never got to write. During his infamous trip to Boston he told it to one of his pen pals in Australia and then he used it when he moved to Ireland and it spread to England and America during the great potato famine. Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Love your new profile pic!

Comment: @FF: I think it's probably a dream sequence style narrative where Michael Stipe is reflecting on himself from a disembodied standpoint.

Comment: @tylerharms: Gotcha. Not really the same thing as *"That's me cleaned out"* said after losing the last of your money/chips in a poker game.

Comment: @FF: Well, maybe if you're trying to detach yourself from a crushing loss, "That's me cleaned out" might be easier to swallow than "I just got cleaned out".

Answer (score 3):

FF, the "that's you done" structure is very British. I consider it essentially unknown in AmE. Just the opinion of someone who has spoken to (literally) hundreds of thousands of people (don't ask why) over the course of many decades.

The Stipe/Simon lyrics are, again in my opinion, merely stylizations intended to draw attention to the person speaking, in the same way one would say "that's me" when pointing to a picture of oneself. They do not equate to the usage that occasioned your initial question.

And I have my own question about the fascinating yet baffling comment concerning Dickens... is that facetious, or what?

Comment: Dunno exactly what happened re the comment - maybe I and/or Steve Blinder got mixed up with [this ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/), where I said Dickens habitually wrote "wos" instead of "was" when transcribing the reported speech of lower-class characters. Which I seriously doubt meaningfully reflects any specific variant of "standard pronunciation". It's just that anyone capable of reading the book in the first place can't avoid recognising the misspelling, reminding them the speaker is uneducated/coarse spoken.

Answer (score -1):

In America, the phrase, "That's me out, then" with slight variations, relates directly to card playing, usually folding in poker. So, originally, the references (object?) of "that's" was quite clear in context.

"That's all for me today" is also quite common, although not quite the construction you're looking at.

The "here's me doing..." type phrase shows up in the speech of some people in the rural deep south but they have a lot of Old English language patterns as the region tended to be somewhat isolated before electronic media and the had very little immigration.

I would hazard that you find that these phrases always have the speaker as the object. Saying the same thing to someone else would sound dominating and rude to most Americans.