# Trailing interjection? "So, I'll just take that, then" Is the "then" now? Should it be "than" because I'm taking it rather than you?

Tags: question-tags, interjections

This question [Are constructions like "That's me out, then" primarily British rather than American?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/are-constructions-like-thats-me-out-then-primarily-british-rather-than-ameri) is more about "that's"

This question's answers [When a person replies with a sentence starting with "then"/"than", should it be then or than?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189416/when-a-person-replies-with-a-sentence-starting-with-then-than-should-it-be) are very close, but the "then" is almost a conjunction there, not an offhand interjection

Related, the "yes", "right", "no", "ja", and "okay" in

- The one around the corner, yes?
- And we'll meet again on Tuesday, right?
- We don't want to be too hasty, no?
- We've covered this topic before, ja?
- So we will only stay a little while, okay?

do not read like classic question-tags as they do not use a form of "to be". They might confirmatory  or leading

This is not in the form of a question, but it feels the same to me

- We'll see you at the party, then

Even when the sentence has a question mark, sometimes it's not really asking (allofunctional implicature); I just want to know what that last word is called and if it should ever be "than"

Cheers

Comment: In your examples, "then" amounts to *based on that*, *therefore*, or *thus*, and not an interjection.  Restrict "than" to comparisons.

Comment: Right. _Than_ occurs strictly with comparative constructions (generally with _more_ or _-er_).

Comment: No idea why it would be "than". I can't see any implied comparison or anything. Is it just that you misheard it as "than" once, or someone mis-wrote? Why isn't it "thin" or "thon"?

Comment: In discourse analysis, "then" at the end like that would be anaphoric. It refers to what another speaker has said.

Comment: 'Then' has a bleached pragmatic role, as seen in "Right; I'd better be off, then." It's a hedged form of "So, moving on ...", a polite way to signal that you consider it's time to leave the conversation. / In contrast, "You have to be at the dentist's at eleven? You'd better get moving, then" uses the 'that being the case' sense. / "We'll see you at the party, then" could be either usage; context will disambiguate. With the proper intonation, it could even be a declarative question, again with 'then' in either role (the conversation-end-marker becoming a conversation-v-near-the-end marker).

Answer (score 1):

[TFD defines](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/then) "then" in this sense as "as a consequence; therefore." There's nothing particularly special about this usage of *then*; the comma is used to avoid violating the rules of adverb positioning, which are generally loosened when the adverb is prosodically detached as indicated by commas.

Comment: It's anaphoric, referring back to another speaker's speech.

Answer (score -1):

[MW defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then) "then" in this sense (adverb definition 3b) as "in that case". Their example is "take it, then, if you want it so much".

Definition 5 in [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/then) is "in that case; accordingly", which is similar.

This is easily seen as an extension of the meaning "at that time" (definition 1 in both TFD and MW), with "case" (= "set of circumstances or conditions", definition 1a in MW) instead of "time".

Comment: Please give citations and examples

Comment: The downvote is possibly because alphabet gave this definition. // As I say in the comment, 'then' is also used as a pragmatic device, bleached of matrix-sentence–referential meaning, as a polite signing-off device. A sentence-initial 'Righto!' was once often used similarly.